# lambda - user is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:ListUsers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have encountered below error when I am trying to get all users in my user pool during testing in Lambda.

```
"errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
"errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/xxxxx is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-west-2:123456789:userpool/us-west-2_abcdefg",
```

My code in lambda:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = () => {
var params = {
  UserPoolId: 'us-west-2_abcdefg',
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-2', 'accessKeyId': 'accesskey', 'secretAccessKey': 'secretkey' });
    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err)
        }
        else {
            console.log("data", data);
            resolve(data)
        }
    })
});
};
```

I tried to add inline policy in IAM but still same error:
[image]

Lambda IAM Role
[image]

I knew I should update json for the policy, but Can someone provide detailed step to update the json policy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your error `cognito-idp:ListUsers` is about **Conginto User Pools**, not Cognito User Identities. So your policy should be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:ListUsers",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For other people who encounter the same error, please note that you should add the policy for the USER instead of Role, because the problem is due to the user permission but not the role of your lambda function

Answer (score 12):

It's just a permission issue. Follow the following steps :

**I. CREATING THE POLICY (FOR PERMISSION)**

1. Go to IAM console -> Policies -> Create Policy.
2. Choose "Cognito User Pools" Services.
3. Specify the desired actions for which you need permission for (List, Read, etc.)
4. Specify Resources.
5. Choose request conditions (optional).
6. Add Tags (Optional).
7. Give name and description of the policy.
8. Click on "Create Policy" button.

**POLICY CREATED.**

**II. ADDING THE POLICY TO THE USER :**

1. Go to IAM console -> Users.
2. Select the desired user.
3. In permissions tab, click on Add Permissions.
4. Click on "Attach existing policy directly".
5. Search for the policy you just created.
6. Click on "Add Permissions"

**ISSUE IS RESOLVED.**

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked for me :

**Step : 1**
I have created a new policy with below json from IAM console

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cognito-identity:MergeDeveloperIdentities",
            "cognito-identity:DescribeIdentityPool",
            "cognito-identity:ListIdentityPools",
            "cognito-identity:CreateIdentityPool",
            "cognito-identity:ListIdentities",
            "cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity",
            "cognito-identity:GetOpenIdToken",
            "cognito-identity:GetIdentityPoolRoles",
            "cognito-identity:GetPrincipalTagAttributeMap",
            "cognito-identity:GetId",
            "cognito-identity:LookupDeveloperIdentity",
            "cognito-identity:UnlinkDeveloperIdentity",
            "cognito-identity:ListTagsForResource",
            "cognito-identity:UpdateIdentityPool",
            "cognito-identity:UnlinkIdentity",
            "cognito-identity:DescribeIdentity",
            "cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

**Step: 2** Added the policy to ecsInstanceRole