# How do I list all users in my Cognito User Pool in my React application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I have a CMS application which site editors can log into. I want to create a dashboard for the editors to be able to create and delete site users. Site user accounts will be maintained through a AWS Cognito User Pool, while site editors log in through their account with the CMS.

To begin with, I want to be able to list all users in a given user pool for the editors to view, so I'm following the SDK docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/index.html), but it doesn't explain how to pass any credentials to the method. This is with v3 of the SDK, and any examples I can find that does something similar uses v2.

I get this far:

```js
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, ListUsersCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";

const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: "eu-west-2" });
const params = {};
const command = new ListUsersCommand({ UserPoolId: "My_User_Pool_Id" });

try {
    const data = await client.send(command);
    return this.setState({ users: data });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return this.setState({ error: error });
} finally {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
}
```

But this gives me an error when I run the above code and render the component:

```
Error: Credential is missing
    at SignatureV4.credentialProvider (runtimeConfig.browser.js:15)
    at SignatureV4.<anonymous> (SignatureV4.js:169)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at tslib.es6.js:74
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:70)
    at SignatureV4.signRequest (SignatureV4.js:165)
    at SignatureV4.<anonymous> (SignatureV4.js:85)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
```

I assume I need to create some credentials (through IAM?) for my dashboard to access the user pools, but I don't know where to create these or how to pass them to the SDK. Googling around this subject seemed to suggest I should make an unauthenticated *Identity* Pool and attached IAM permissions to that, then pass that pool's credentials to the SDK, but that gave me permissions errors too:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: [DashboardAdmin IdentityPool ARN] is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:ListUsers on resource: [UserPool for Site Users ARN]
```

Comment: How does your app authenticate site editors?

Comment: The CMS (Sanity.io) comes with its own authentication and login flow for editors. We have a separate authentication system for site users as we don't need/want users to be able to access the CMS portion of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the correct part of the v3 docs around getting and setting credentials.

You get credentials by creating them through a new IAM user for your application, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-your-credentials.html).

There are then multiple different ways you can add them to your app, as per [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html), depending on whether you're working on the server side or the client side. For example, hard-coding them on the server-side requires this change:

```js
const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: "eu-west-2" });
```

change to

```js
const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
    region: "eu-west-2",
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
});
```

Then, the error `User is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:ListUsers on resource` is solved by adding a policy allowing cognito-idp:ListUsers to the IAM user you created above. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64533480/10228954) steered me in the correct direction for that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the guide, but as mentioned, this is a risk. "While it is possible to do so, we recommend you not hard code credentials inside an application or browser script. Hard coding credentials poses a risk of exposing your access key ID and secret access key."

Answer (score 1):

You can get current user's credentials by following code and set it to cognito client.

```
import { Amplify, Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';
const credentials = await Amplify.Auth.currentCredentials()
```