# Updating custom user attributes on AWS cognito with a number value (via a post confirmation trigger / lambda function)

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-triggers

I have a lambda trigger in my user pool (post confirmation lambda trigger), which calls the code below:

```
sess, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to create session", err.Error())
    }

    svc := cognitoidentityprovider.New(sess)

    params := &cognitoidentityprovider.AdminUpdateUserAttributesInput{
        UserAttributes: []*cognitoidentityprovider.AttributeType{
            {
                Name:  aws.String("custom:onboarding"),
                Value: aws.Int(0),
            },
        },
        UserPoolId: aws.String("xxxxx"),
        Username:   aws.String("xxxxx"),
    }

    resp, err := svc.AdminUpdateUserAttributes(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("resp error: ", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
```

Im receiving the following error:

```
.\main.go:36:5: cannot use "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws".Int(0) (type *int) as type *string in field value
```

The value needs to be an integer, as the custom attribute is set as a number in cognito.

What am I missing here? Or is this not the right method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: follow the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeType.html Value has a string type. So, looks like you need smth like Value: aws.String("0")

Comment: @isavinof - the problem is that the attribute doesn't get added in the cognito backend and I suspect that its because 'custom:onboarding' is a number value not string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. As isavinof said, the value has a string type, which wasn't working initially, however, it turned out to be a permissions error ( AccessDeniedException ).

To fix the problem, I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67678111/1898662

I. CREATING THE POLICY (FOR PERMISSION)

- Go to IAM console -> Policies -> Create Policy.
- Choose "Cognito User Pools" Services.
- Specify the desired actions for which you need permission for (List, Read,
  etc.) In this case, it was write -> AdminUpdateUserAttributesInput
- Specify Resources - the userpool region and id
- Choose request conditions (optional).
- Add Tags (Optional) - helps with searching in a large list of policies
- Give name and description of the policy - be exact as it helps to ensure
  you have chosen the right one in the next stage
- Click on "Create Policy" button.
  POLICY CREATED.

II. ADDING THE POLICY TO THE USER :

- Go to IAM console -> Users (in this case, roles, not users, and find the lambda function role. If you don't know it, view it in the lambda backend, under permissions)
- Select the desired role.
- In permissions tab, click on Add Permissions.
- Click on "Attach existing policy directly".
- Search for the policy you just created.
- Click on "Add Permissions"
  ISSUE IS RESOLVED.